# How can I create a column in an existing df from dictionary and using conditions?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following df (just for example):

```
data={'Name': ['Tom', 'Joseph', 'Krish', 'John']}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

city={"New York": "123", 
 "LA":"456",
 "Miami":"789"}

Output:
     Name
0     Tom
1  Joseph
2   Krish
3    John
```

I would like to add another column to the df which will be based on the city dictionary.

I would like to do it by the following conditions:
If the Name is Tom or Krish then they should get 123 (New York).
If the Name is John then he should get 456 (LA).
If the Name is Joseph then he should get 789 (Miami).

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try via loc and boolean masking:

```
df.loc[df['Name'].isin(['Tom','Krish']),'City']='New York'
df.loc[df['Name'].eq('Joseph'),'City']='LA'
df.loc[df['Name'].eq('John'),'City']='Miami'
```

Finally:

```
df['Value']=df['City'].map(city)
#you can also use replace() in place of map()
```

OR

```
#import numpy as np
cond=[
    df['Name'].isin(['Tom','Krish']),
    df['Name'].eq('Joseph'),
    df['Name'].eq('John')                     
]
df['City']=np.select(cond,['New York','LA','Miami'])
df['Value']=df['City'].map(city)
```